# Set onItemClickListener on only a particular card in CardScrollView?

Tags: android, google-glass, cardscrollview

I am making a quiz app in the google glass. 
After the clicking the main activity (Which is a question) the user is taken to a list of cards, in mCardScrollView (which are answers to the question in main activity), I want user to be taken to the next question only after the correct option (i.e card in cardscrollview) is clicked.

Currently I am using the following itemclicklistener which turns every card to a clickable item,

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // Plays disallowed sound to indicate that TAP actions are not supported.
            AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            am.playSoundEffect(Sounds.DISALLOWED);

            Toast.makeText(Questionactivity.this, "this is selected : " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //mCardScrollView.deactivate();


            Intent gotoquestion;
            gotoquestion = new Intent(Questionactivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(gotoquestion);
            finish();
```

And I am trying to do something as follows on one of the card in cardscrollview,

```
       mCards.add(new CardBuilder(this, CardBuilder.Layout.COLUMNS)
            .setText("This card has a mosaic of puppies.")
            .setFootnote("Aren't they precious?")
            .addImage(R.drawable.ic_glass_logo));
            .View.OnClickListener
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simple if-logic to identify the cards you don't want with a return true should do what you want without performing any action.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    if (!aClickableCard) {
        return true;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Sorry.  You completely changed the question.  You need to ask another question rather than adding a "part 2" -- doubly so when part 2 is entirely different.